# Model a process as a poisson process

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I just answered this question on coloring balls at a fixed rate - [Interesting Original Probability Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462327/interesting-original-probability-question/1463057#1463057). This problem seems to have all the ingredients to model as a poisson distribution with rate = 1 ball per minute. But the expected value calculation is off by a large value. Can we model this problem as a poisson distribution? More generally, if a process has a fixed rate of events (1 ball per minute) that happen independently and randomly, then I can apply poisson process. Are there any other conditions?

Comment: For sure a ball gets coloured every minute, though it may already have been coloured. And for sure no more than one. That's very un-Poisson behaviour.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But isn't that analogous to the coupon collector problem where we can draw coupons at a fixed rate( though it may already have been seen) and find time $t$ till we get all coupons? Coupon collector is a well modelled poisson process.

Comment: If after picking we decided whether to colour, and we coloured with smallish probability, then one might get a reasonable it.